# How to set the value of a string varible when a button (specified in fxml) is clicked using java code

Tags: java, javafx

In my controller.java file , i have something like this

```
@FXML
private button bt;
```

In the FXML file it is like this

```xml
<Button fx:id="bt"......>
```

When this button is clicked i want to set the value of a string  .
That is

```
Query="button clicked"
```

What function should be used to perform this?

I am using IntelliJ.

Comment: I suggest using a event handler: `<Button onAction="#buttonClick" />` controller: `@FXML private void buttonClick() { ... }` but what exactly the `buttonClick` method should contain depends on the place where `Query` is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.

This solution is a part of swing, im not sure about JavaFx, but this requires your `button` to be a `JButton` and that you `import javax.swing.*;` and `import java.awt.event.ActionListener;`

You can add a `ActionListener` to your button. Inside the `ActionListener` class you need a method called `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`, which is the method that runs when a user clicks your button.

e.g.

```
import javax.swing;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
JButton bt = new JButton("Button Text");

bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
  Query = "button clicked";

 }
}
);
```

Comment: The question is tagged JavaFx. I suspect your answer relates to  Swing.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller class, you must define a method that performs the action that you are attempting (in this case, changing the contents of the string) and add this action to the button's onAction property in your FXML document.

For example,

```
String Query = new String();

@FXML
private button bt;    .
.
.
.

@FXML
private void setString(ActionEvent event){
    Query = "button clicked";
}
```

Once the method is defined, in your FXML file, set the button's onAction parameter to the name of the method, using a "#" in front of the method name

```
<Button fx:id="bt" onAction = "#setString" />
```